# FileSystemWatcher didnt invoke change event

Tags: c#, events, xml-serialization, filesystemwatcher

I wrote the following code.

```
 [XmlRoot("myxml")]
public class myxml
{
    [XmlElement("one")]
    public string one { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("two")]
    public string two { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

  // 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myxml m = new myxml();
        m.one = "111";
        m.two = "222";
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\", "myxml.xml");
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\myxml.xml", FileMode.Open);
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(m.GetType());
        x.Serialize(fs, m);
        fs.Close();



    }
}
```

now I thought that after the following line OnChanged event will invoked but no...

```
x.Serialize(fs, m);
```

also after this line nothing happened

```
fs.Close();
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set EnableRaisingEvents to true in order to start raising events.

Comment: Thank you, and after witch line it will raise? after`x.Serialize(fs, m);` or after `fs.Close();`

Comment: I don't know if Serialize will flush the IO buffer but certainly Close will do. However using your program it's absolutely possible and I think highly probable to have nothing printed because watcher doesn't get the chance to fire the event, the program terminates after the call to Close.

Comment: it is only test application to see if it raise the event,I just need to be sure that the onChange event will raise only after i complete serialize the file.